# Draw text on oval path in the centre

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw some text on path using the canvas in Android. I can successfully get the text to draw on the top oval line. What i'm struggling to do is make sure that the text is centered.

The problem is that while i can measure the text before it gets drawn round the top line of the oval, i cannot measure it after. This makes estimating where the text should be drawn on the top oval line problematic as it's always a little bit out. This is because when i measure the text to be drawn initially it is measured in a straight line and not as presented on the top line of the oval.

I've tried applying `setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER)` but this makes the text get drawn about 3/4's of the way round and not what i want.

Does anyone have any ideas how i could calculate the point to draw the text so it is drawn dead centre of the top oval line or any alternative method that may help?

This has to be drawn using the canvas. It can't be done using XML TextViews etc.

Thanks.

[image: Oval to have text drawn on top of]

Comment: Try to use `drawTextOnPath()`

Comment: That's what I am using but they problem is making sure the text is centred on the top half line of the oval. I can successfully get the text to draw at the top, it's dynamically making sure the text is centred that's the issue.

Comment: One way is to calculate the width of the rendered text using Paint.getTextBounds() and then define the Path accordingly, which will eliminate the need to apply alignment on the text.
Ideally the alignment thing should have worked as per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)

Comment: I've also tried that but the issue there is that text is measured in a straight line. When the text is applied to the top half of the oval it's straight line measurement is shorter. This means it's always out of centre by a little bit.

Comment: Yup, exactly. So now in order to determine the start of the text, what should be needed is to calculate the (horizontal width of the) curved path using value returned by getTextBounds(), considering that the vertical center of the text is at an offset from the oval path.

Comment: So you're saying: measure text, draw oval based on the length of text, draw text on path of oval with alignment centre?

Comment: Could you share the output which you've obtained?

Comment: Yes, it is not the ideal way... But it should work. :)
Also again the oval size can be anything. Just that the origin (pivot) of the text can be calculated based on oval eccentricity and width of the text.

Comment: OK thanks I'll give it a go :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108613/discussion-between-mike-scamell-and-sahil-bajaj).

Answer (score 0):

You can check how this library done it: https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable

Its using the same approach. But for multiple lines its almost impossible, theres an issue on this library where me and other developers tried to implement it, and we end up using just xml (a round drawable as a linearLayout view background and one textView inside it).

Comment: It has to be drawn using canvas and not XML. Also to clarify I only want to draw the text on the top line of the ellipsis. Not in the middle of it. Thanks though.